# Service Reference does not update with service on remote WinHost Site

Tags: .net, wcf

My changes to a data transfer object on the server-side are not being reflected within the client's service reference.

**THIS ONLY OCCURS ON THE REMOTE SERVER.**
*When I run the service locally, the client's service reference updates as expected.*

1. I have deleted and re-added the service reference.
2. I have published the service to a different location on the remote server.
3. I have changed the name of the class and the service reference does not update to it.
4. I have added members with datamember attributes.
5. I have removed members.

Regardless of everything that I have done, my service reference continues to reference the original class with the same name and the same members despite my changes.

Again this only happens on the remote server.

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do the following:

To have multiple applications running on your site without them affecting each other, you will need to set the subfolders as application starting points in your Site Manager.

Here are instructions on how to configure a subdirectory as a web application:

1) Log into the WinHost Control Panel [here](https://cp.winhost.com)

2) Click on the Sites tab.

3) Click on the Manage link next to the site you want to manage.

4) Click on the Application Starting Point button.

5) Use the Create button to mark the directory.

I updated my webconfig with the following:

```
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="services/post/bin" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```